# Fundamental group acts properly discontinuously on universal cover

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, group-actions, fundamental-groups

I would like to prove the following.

> Let $M$ be a closed manifold. Then $\pi_1(M)$ acts properly discontinuously on its universal cover $\tilde{M}$.

Here I am using the definition of a properly discontinuous action to be that for all compact $K \subset \tilde{M}$, the set $\{ g \in \pi_1 (M) : gK \cap K \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite.

My incomplete attempt goes as follows. Assume for a contradiction that there exists a sequence of distinct elements $\{ g_i \}_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $ g_i K \cap K \neq \emptyset $. Then for all $g_i$ there exists some (distinct) $k_i$ such that $k_i \in g_i K \cap K$. Since in particular all such $k_i$ belongs in $K$, and it is an infinite set, there is a limit point $k$ inside $K$.

This is where I'm stuck. I would assume I take a small enough open neighborhood $U$ of $k$ and use properties of the covering map $p : \tilde{M} \to M$ to show that this neighborhood never intersects any $gU$ for all $g \in \pi_1(M)$ and this would yield a contradiction with the above argument in $K$, but I don't know how to flesh this out. I also know that the action is co-compact, if this is of any use.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed on the right track.

Take a neighborhood $U$ of $k$ such that $\bigsqcup_g gU$ is the even covering of $p(U)$ (this can be done for instance by taking an evenly covered disk around $p(k)$ and noticing that its preimage must be one disk around each point of the orbit $Gk$). But by construction of $k$, there are infinitely many $k_i \in U$, which means $g_i k_i \in g_i U \cap K$ for infinitely many $g_i$.
Then the set $\{g_i k_i\} \cap K$ is discrete, infinite and compact (since it's closed in $K$) which is a contradiction.